# Payu (kenya) payment integration using soap in php

Tags: php, zend-framework, payment-gateway, payu

I have a problem with PayU integration in **Zend Framework (3.2)** with SOAP API.
Please let me know where i doing wrong also i'm hitting API with SOAP UI 5.5 and got **Error reading XMLStreamReader.**

But i got a below error:-

**Class 'SoapVar' not found**

```
        $baseUrl = 'https://staging.payu.co.za';
        $soapWdslUrl = $baseUrl.'/service/PayUAPI?wsdl';
        $payuRppUrl = $baseUrl.'/rpp.do?PayUReference=';
        $apiVersion = 'ONE_ZERO';
        $safeKey = '{0B387E02-870B-477F-BCD5-0541199ADC19}';
        $soapUsername = '200257';
        $soapPassword = 'JHVH6z1r';
        $merchantReference = "merchant_ref_".time();;

        $doTransactionArray = array();
        $doTransactionArray['Api'] = $apiVersion;
        $doTransactionArray['Safekey'] = $safeKey;
        $doTransactionArray['TransactionType'] = 'PAYMENT';     

        $doTransactionArray['AdditionalInformation']['merchantReference'] = $merchantReference;
        $doTransactionArray['Basket']['description'] = "Sudhir";
        $doTransactionArray['Basket']['amountInCents'] = "1";
        $doTransactionArray['Basket']['currencyCode'] = 'KES';
        $doTransactionArray['Customer']['merchantUserId'] = "7";
        $doTransactionArray['Customer']['email'] = "john@doe.com";
        $doTransactionArray['Customer']['firstName'] = 'John';
        $doTransactionArray['Customer']['lastName'] = 'Doe';
        $doTransactionArray['Customer']['mobile'] = '0211234567';
        $doTransactionArray['Customer']['regionalId'] = '1234512345122';
        $doTransactionArray['Customer']['countryCode'] = '27';
        $doTransactionArray['Creditcard']['nameOnCard'] = "Mr John Doe";
        $doTransactionArray['Creditcard']['cardNumber'] = "5453010000064261";
        $doTransactionArray['Creditcard']['cardExpiry'] = "0521";
        $doTransactionArray['Creditcard']['cvv'] = "123";  
        $doTransactionArray['Creditcard']['amountInCents'] = $doTransactionArray['Basket']['amountInCents']; 
        try {
            $soapDataArray = array();    
            $soapDataArray = array_merge($soapDataArray, $doTransactionArray );

            $headerXml = '<wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">';
            $headerXml .= '<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-9" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">';
            $headerXml .= '<wsse:Username>'.$soapUsername.'</wsse:Username>';
            $headerXml .= '<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">'.$soapPassword.'</wsse:Password>';
            $headerXml .= '</wsse:UsernameToken>';
            $headerXml .= '</wsse:Security>';
            $headerbody = new \SoapVar($headerXml, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);

            // 3. Create Soap Header.        
            $ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'; //Namespace of the WS. 
            $header = new \SOAPHeader($ns, 'Security', $headerbody, true);           
            $soap_client = new \SoapClient($soapWdslUrl, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0)); 
            $soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header); 
            $soapCallResult = $soap_client->doTransaction($soapDataArray); 
            $returnData = json_decode(json_encode($soapCallResult),true);

            $decodedXmlData = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($returnData)),true); 

        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e);
            die();
        }
```

Comment: you need to update "new SoapVar" to "new \SoapVar" -- because it's assuming "SoapVar" is a class with the same namespace as the file you're in... hence why it's trying to call:
Application\Utility\Payment\Zend\SoapVar

Comment: Still got error Class &#039;SoapVar&#039; not found